# assign value to string in Razor

Tags: html, string, razor, model-view-controller

I am trying to assign a value in string in razor here is my code

```
{@string Address='India'}
```

but it is giving syntax error what should be the right syntax

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `@{string address = "India"};`